# Esri JS Api 4.18 requires ncp copy of node_modles for BUILD and START. what and were do I need to copy assets for working in storybook.js

Tags: javascript, esri, storybook, arcgis-js-api

To use the ES modules for esri JS Api 4.18 requires ncp copy of node_modules for BUILD and START.  what and where do I need to copy assets for working in storybook.js?

Copy assets

You will need to copy the API’s assets, which includes styles, images, fonts, and localization files, from the @arcgis/core/assets folder to your build folder. A simple way to accomplish this is to configure an NPM script that runs during your build process. For example, use npm to install ncp and configure a script in package.json to copy the folder. Here’s a React example:

```
// package.json

    {
        "script": {
            "start": "npm run copy && react-scripts start",
            "build": "npm run copy && react-scripts build",
            "copy": "ncp ./node_modules/@arcgis/core/assets ./public/assets"
        }
    }
```

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/es-modules/

Answer (score 0):

ok so turns out it is pretty easy.  You need to ncp copy your asset files to a common directory in your project and you need to reference it in your storybook script.

```
{
    "scripts": {
       "start-storybook": "npm run copy && start-storybook -s ./public -p 9001"
       "copy": "ncp ./node_modules/@arcgis/core/assets ./public/assets"
    }
}
```

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets